# How to hide shape/chart in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to find the solution on the internet, but none of them worked for my situation.

I have the following chart and I want to hide it, but I don't know how:

```
Dim cht As Chart

Sub CreatePie()
    arrColors = Array(RGB(183, 212, 117), _
                      RGB(0, 93, 172))
    Set cht = Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes.AddChart(Left:=600, Width:=160, Top:=290, Height:=90).Chart
    With cht
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("M5:N6")
        .ChartType = xlPie
        .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Solid
        .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Transparency = 1
        .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = arrColors(0)
        .Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = arrColors(1)
    End With
    cht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden   
End Sub
```

`cht.Visible = False` doesn't work either.

Deleting it is also an option, but `cht.Delete` doesn't work either.

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `Parent` (the `ChartObject`) in order to hide the whole chart. So instead of your line :

```
cht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

modify to :

```
cht.Parent.Visible = False
```